# How Do I Do 'Words Starting With' in Python?

Tags: python, string, string-comparison

The title should be pretty self explanatory, though to give an example:

```
runny=input(print("do you run or stay?"))
if runny in ["run", "Run", " run", " Run", "run ", "Run ", " run ", " Run "]:
```

I just wanted to know if I could say like 'if runny stars with char (r) or something?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could transform your input to reduce the search space.

1. lowercase letters
2. remove trailing spaces

---

```
if 'run' in runny.lower():
    # do something
```

Or, with an exact match:

```
if 'run' == runny.lower().strip():
    # do something
```

You could also use `str.startswith`, but beware of false positives:

```
if runny.lstrip().lower().startswith('run'):
    # do something
```

If you need to account for spaces *between* characters, or more complex patterns, you should go with regex.

Comment: So I am assuming that the 'runny.lower()' turn the answer to lowercase, and the '.strip()' strips the spaces, are they supposed to be connected like that though? Also from the answer above, if I were to use regex, could you help to explain what exactly this piece of code does 'if re.match(r"(\s|^)run(\s|$)",runny,flags=re.I):'?

Comment: @QuestionedE yes, because string methods return new transformed strings, so you can chain string method calls. Can't do that for, say lists or dicts.

Comment: @COLDSPEED Thanks! Just in case you didn't see my edit (sorry) what exactly does "if re.match(r"(\s|^)run(\s|$)",runny,flags=re.I):" do if I were to use regex?

Comment: @QuestionedE You should understand that regex is the worst possible approach to use, when your problem is this simple. There's a saying... if you use regex to solve a problem... you have 2 problems. :p

Comment: You don't need the `strip` for `in` search! It can never help!

Comment: @AnttiHaapala True... not with `in`, but I would need it if I were doing an `==` check (mentioned that in the comment, decided to keep it in to prevent confusion)

Comment: And actually you didn't address the startswith requirement with this.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to run a `print` function inside `input`.  You end up printing an extra `None`. Next you should be using regex for this as it makes it a lot more maintainable.

```
import re
runny=input("do you run or stay? ")
if re.match(r"\brun\b",runny,flags=re.I):
    print("You're running!")
else:
    print("You're not running.")
```